# Select only numeric and ";"

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a sample dataset in a table. I want to make changes while selecting in this data set. How can I do it?

Example table:

```
ID VAL
1 1.abc; 2.bcd; 3.a-sd; 4.fhg
2 5.bsfacd; 3.afgh-sd; 4.fvbnbhg
```

The result I want is:

```
ID VAL
1 1;2;3;4;
2 5;3;4;
```

How can I get this result with a select statement?

Comment: By not storing your data like that in the first place, would be my suggestion. Normalise your design. That means not storing delimited data, and *certainly* not storing delimited data with labels.

Comment: Yes I know, I just need an urgent solution right now. @ThomA

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest) TL;DR: Never.

Comment: are you using sql server 2022 or azure? or some older version? you probably need string_split with ordinal parameter available for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so while you know storing multiple atomic values in a column is probably one of the biggest anti-patterns, one possible solution for your situation is to make use of `translate` and `replace`:

```
with dodgy as (
  select * from (values
    (1, '1.abc; 2.bcd; 3.a-sd; 4.fhg'),
    (2, '5.bsfacd; 3.afgh-sd; 4.fvbnbhg')
  )d(Id, Val)
)
select * , Concat(
    Replace(Translate(
      Val, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.-', 
      Replicate(' ', 28)
    ), ' ',''), ';'
  ) StillDodgy
from dodgy;
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Personally, like I mentioned, I would normalise your data and then just leave it like that. As your data is JSON *like* you could attempt to convert it to JSON, then you can consume that JSON and have a *good* data set:

```sql
SELECT V.ID,
       OJ.[Key] AS Value, --Maybe wants a TRY_CONVERT to an int?
       OJ.Value AS Label
FROM (VALUES(1,'1.abc; 2.bcd; 3.a-sd; 4.fhg'),
            (2,'5.bsfacd; 3.afgh-sd; 4.fvbnbhg'))V(ID,VAL)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES('{"' + REPLACE(REPLACE(VAL,'.','":"'),'; ','","')+ '"}'))J(JSON)
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(J.JSON) OJ;
```